# OpenKey Windows 7

Tags: c++

what have of wrong here ? Work in my notebook, but not in my PC . . . 
The two are 64-bits, Windows 7 ultimate.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    HKEY CH;
    char File_Name[] = "C:\\Users\\RMS\\Desktop\\M.txt";

    if(RegCreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",&CH) != 0){
                                             printf("Erro - RegCreateKey\n");
                                             system("PAUSE");
                                              return -1;
   }
    if(RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",&CH) != 0) // Abre a CH "Minha CH"
    {
        printf("Erro - RegOpenKey\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }
    if(RegSetValueEx(CH,L"My_Value",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE) L"C:\\Users\\RMS\\Desktop\\M.txt",40) != 0)
        printf("Erro - RegSetValue\n");
    RegCloseKey(CH);
    printf("\nsucesso !\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I found. . . Was only do this:

> ```
>     if(RegSetValueEx(CH,L"My_Value",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE) L"C:\\Users\\RMS\\Desktop\\M.txt",60) != 0)
> ```

VERY THANK GUYS !!

Comment: what error do you get

Comment: Your code doesn't use the function correctly. It should be comparing the result against `ERROR_SUCCESS`. It also isn't respecting UAC, as writing to HKLM requires admin privileges under Vista and above (or XP when running under other than a local admin or power user account). When using the WinAPI, **use the documentation** available at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com), and **check the return values** according to that documentation.

Comment: @KenWhite Am I right in assuming that this program should implicitely result in a UAC confirmation prompt to the user, then? Or does UAC require the programmer to take special action(s) to allow such a thing happen?

Comment: It depends. If UAC is in effect, it will virtualize the registry key, which means that the write may appear to work but not be actually completed. You can Google UAC and virtualization to see how that can impact things (and there have been many posts here previously). UAC and restricted access has been around more than a decade now, so there has been a lot written about it.

Comment: For some operations its implicit, but for others it will just fail. There are APIs to require the privilege, but right now I don't remember how.

Comment: Sorry - replace "will virtualize" with "under some circumstances, can virtualize". Didn't catch it fast enough to edit the comment itself.

Comment: RegOpenKey "is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Applications should use the RegOpenKeyEx function."   With RegOpenKeyEx, you can specify whether you want to open the key only for reading (which should be permissible for most users) or for writing (which requires a privileged account).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `HKLM` registry key is only writable by elevated programs, and your program is not running elevated. The reason it works on one machine and not the other is that one has user access control turned down/off while the other doesn't.

If you ran the program from an elevated command prompt it will work.

Additionally, you're using `L""` for the strings, but using a `RegSetValueEx` call with 40, which is 40 **bytes**, and will actually cut off the `M.txt` on the text you're setting (if it works at all). Where you initialize the `.txt` file you should use:

```
TCHAR File_Name[] = L"C:\\Users\\RMS\\Desktop\\M.txt";
```

Then for the RegSetValueEx you do:

```
RegSetValueEx(CH,L"My_Value",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE) File_Name, sizeof File_Name + sizeof(TCHAR))
```

This makes it the number of bytes that corresponds to the filename, plus the final NULL TCHAR.

Comment: I execute this program how administrator !

Comment: I don't quite understand the statement/question.

Answer (score -1):

what error do you get?

try

```
RegOpenKeyEx
```

instead of RegOpenKey, since that's for 16 bit windows.

Comment: worst part is that I have no error

Comment: well what does the program output then?

Comment: All of those functions provide information when there's an error, you're just not using it.

Comment: output: The program '[3336] autoexe.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: 0 Erros 0 Warnings !!!

Comment: The worst part is that have no list of error

Comment: Theres no such thing as 16 bit Windows.

Comment: @AlessandraSantos "0 Erros 0 Warnings 3 Exclamation marks 1 Typos" ?

Comment: `RegOpenKey` is a macro that will select `RegOpenKeyA` or `RegOpenKeyW` depending if your project is set to use Single-byte characters or Double-byte characters respectively. Both `RegOpenKey` and `RegOpenKeyEx` have those variations.

Comment: I changed RegOpenKey for RegOpenKeyEx. Now I have a error: C2660: 'RegOpenKeyExW' : function does not take 3 arguments . . . Ok this other function have a number different of arguments

Comment: Guys, I did in my regedit . . . see what I have in my "run" AND !!  I have only "C:\\Users\\RMS\\Desktop\\" . . . And I need "C:\\Users\\RMS\\Desktop\\M.txt . . . Sorry my english .... I am learn it . . .

Comment: OK ...... I did work !!! 
I changed:
This line:
    if(RegSetValueEx(CH,L"My_Value",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE) L"C:\\Users\\RMS\\Desktop\\M.txt",40) != 0)
To this line:
 if(RegSetValueEx(CH,L"M.txt",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE) L"C:\\Users\\RMS\\Desktop\\M.txt",60) != 0)

Of 40 to 60 . . . LOL this problem was simple

Comment: I THANKS ALL !!! THANK GUYS =D.